# Deallocation doesn't free memory in Windows/C++ Application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management, memory-leaks

My Windows/C++ application allocates ~1Gb of data in memory with the operator `new` and processes this data. After processing the data is deleted.

I noticed that if I run the processing again without exiting the application, the second call to the operator`new` to allocate ~1Gb of data fails.

I would expect Windows to deliver the memory back. Could this be managed in a better way with some other Win32 calls etc.?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is a Windows problem. Check if you used delete or delete[] correctly. Perhaps it would help if you post the code that is allocating/freeing the memory.

Answer (score 5):

In most runtime environments memory allocated to an application from the operating system remains in the application, and is seldom returned back to the operating system.  Freeing a memory block allows you to reuse the block from within the application, but does not free it to the operating system to make it available to other applications.

Microsoft's C runtime library tries to return memory back to the operating system by having _heapmin_region call _heap_free_region or _free_partial_region  which call VirtualFree to release data to the operating system.  However, if whole pages in the corresponding region are not empty, then they will not be freed.  A common cause of this is the bookkeeping information and storage caching of C++ containers.

Comment: This might be the case for Java, but is certainly not the case for Windows standard C/C++ libraries, at least not for anything larger than a memory page. Give it a try and see it yourself.

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer to describe how Microsoft C handles deallocation.

Comment: Where can you definitely read up on details like this?  A MS or printed book reference would be great.  I genuinely don't know where to look and even suspect that there is no where to look and that people find this stuff out by experimentation -- I hope this isn't the case!

Comment: You can find these details in the source code!  That's how I found it, and that's typically the only definite source of truth.

Answer (score 3):

This *could* be due to memory fragmentation (in reality, address space fragmentation), where various factors have contributed to your program address space not having a 1gb contiguous hole available. In reality, I suspect a bug in your memory management (sorry) - have you run your code through leak detection?

Comment: I have made sure that each new'ed pointer is delete'd as well. My debug print logs show this at least.

Are there any tools within VS2003 or standalone to help me look for leaks ?

Comment: Have a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf(VS.80).aspx , which might help. You should also check that any objects you're new'ing that allocate resources must deallocate in their destructors, and that any new[] is matched with delete[].

Comment: I was thinking that delete[] is obsolete and delete is sufficient.

Comment: delete[] is required whenever you use new[] to allocate data.

Comment: Yes, not using delete[] is most likely to be your problem. I should have made that more clear in my answer, I guess.

Comment: Memory fragmentation:  In 32-bit windows, aren't you restricted to a 4gig memory address space?  Or is it 2gig?  If you are trying to allocate ~1gb, wouldn't that require a ~1gb CONTIGUOUS memory block...  So anything else allocated after delete[] would cause memory fragmentation...

Comment: It may also be an idea to call the CRT function '_heapmin' prior to the call to 'new': "The _heapmin function minimizes the heap by releasing unused heap memory to the operating system."

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using very large memory blocks, you should consider using [VirtualAlloc()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366887(VS.85).aspx) and [VirtualFree()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366892(VS.85).aspx), as they allow you to allocate and free pages directly, without the overhead (in memory and time) of interacting with a heap manager.

Since you are using C++, it is worth noting that you can construct C++ objects in the memory you allocate this way by using [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is almost certainly memory fragmentation. On 32 bit Windows the largest contiguous region you can allocate is about 1.1GB (because various DLLs in your EXE preventa  larger contiguous range being available). If after deallocating a memory allocation (or a DLL load, or a memory mapped file) ends up in the middle of your previous 1GB region then there will no longer be a 1GB region available for your next call to new to allocate 1GB. Thus it will fail.

You can visualize this process using [VM Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp/virtual_memory/index.html).